# wxPython - Begin and End BusyCursor

Tags: wxpython

Part of my application produces a complex report that take some time to generate. As this may be a few minutes I would like to put up a BusyCursor() to assure people something is happening. The problem I have is that I need to start it in one module and end it in another. This is because it produces a number of reports including a PDF for immediate viewing and another with associated CSV files for subsequent use.

Comment: Are you running these "other" modules in threads, because at some point, you are going to come back to the `mainloop`, when you can cancel (del or EndBusyCursor depending on your wx) the `BusyCursor`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wxPython have the class wx.StockCursor. This class can create a custom cursor and set into a window area. All cursors is available on: http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.Cursor-class.html

You can use this example code:

```
import wx

class TestFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None)
        self.SetBackgroundColour("#FFFFFF")
        self.rootSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        self.rootSizer.Add((80, 80)) # Spacer
        self.buttonActive = wx.Button(self,-1,"Activate",size=(100,100))
        self.buttonActive.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnActivate)
        self.rootSizer.Add(self.buttonActive,0,wx.ALIGN_CENTER)

        self.rootSizer.Add((80,80)) # Spacer
        self.buttonDisable = wx.Button(self,-1, "Disable", size=(100,100))
        self.buttonDisable.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnDisabled)
        self.rootSizer.Add(self.buttonDisable,0,wx.ALIGN_CENTER)

        self.SetSizer(self.rootSizer)

    def OnActivate(self,evt):
        print "Activate"
        self.SetCursor(wx.StockCursor(wx.CURSOR_WAIT))

    def OnDisabled(self, evt):
        print "Disabled"
        self.SetCursor(wx.StockCursor(wx.CURSOR_ARROW))


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = wx.App(None)
    frame = TestFrame(None)
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: This worked after a certain amount of code restructuring as both the dialog box and time.sleep() appear to block updates of the cursor!